# Finding $5$ numbers knowing their mean and median

Tags: means, median

create a set of five values with a mean of $4$ and a median of $5$. demonstrate that this true

I think that should be $5$ variables but I have only $2$ equations ,so it will be $5$ variables in $2$ equations, how can I solve it?

Comment: There are many possible solutions to this problem. You have to be a little bit creative. I suggest looking for five numbers $a,b,c,d,e$ with $a \le b \le c \le d \le e$, and median $c$ equal to $5$. (And think about it for an hour or so before asking for more help!)

Comment: You are correct you have five variables and only two equations, so you expect  a three dimensional solution space.  You can choose one variable to be $5$ because you need the median in the list.  You can choose the other three at will as long as they straddle $5$, then solve for the fourth from the mean equation.

Comment: So there is no specific answer, i will have more than one scenerio, which means that my answer is correct.

Comment: @RossMillikan: You can't quite choose the other three at will. For instance, $\{3,4,6\}$ wouldn't work because the last would have to be $2$, but then the median would be wrong.

Comment: You need $5$ in your list so it can be the median.   Then you need the smaller numbers to be farther from $5$ than the larger ones so they can pull the mean downward.  if your small numbers are too close to $5$ it won't work, as your example shows.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution:

$$a+b+5+d+e=20$$
$$a+b+d+e=15$$

$$a,b < 5$$

$$d,e > 5$$

Let me try some numbers, let $a=0$, $b=1$.

Then I end up up $d+e=14$

Let $d=6$ and I have found $e=8$.

Comment: I did something like that but the point is that we can't get a specific values for a,b,d,e  1,2,3,9  ,there is nothgin to say that a,b should be less than 5 and d,e should be over 5 ?

Comment: There is the median constraint right? If you choose $1,2,3,5,9$, the median is $3$